# В Opera прыгают блоки по высоте

Tags: html, css

Аномалия, блоки прыгают при наведении на ссылки, то бишь меняют свое положение по вертикали. С "вешалки в театре" я начал, все параметры css сбросил. Думал из-за стиля ссылок, отмена последнего не вылечила. Во всех обозревателях работает исправно, только опера отстает. Как вылечить, подскажите, может кто сталкивался?

Comment: Как вариант какой-нибудь ресет. Я пользуюсь blueprint. Стало лучше, но ишак все равно выпендривается((

Comment: Можно посмотреть "вживую"?